# Pulling Information from Array

Tags: cakephp, multidimensional-array, pagination

```
<pre class="cake-debug">
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Qnote] => Array
            (
                [id] => 67
                [subject] => Call Closing
                [body] => Gave Information

                [user_id] => 39
            )

        [Step] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [user_id] => 39
                        [qnote_id] => 67
                        [type] => a
                        [body] => This is a text
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [user_id] => 39
                        [qnote_id] => 67
                        [type] => a
                        [body] => This is userid 39

                    )



            )

    )
```

)

Hi, I am Trying to pull data from  this array

```
<?php foreach($data as $qnote): ?> 
<?php echo $qnote['Qnote']['id']; ?> // Works
<?php echo $qnote['Qnote']['body']; ?> //Works
<?php echo $qnote['Step']['body']; ?> // Doesnt Work ????
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

what is the right way to  pull up Step Data. 
Could Someone please point me in the right direction.

Controller Code:

```
function view($id = null) {         
$this->Qnote->id = $id;
$userID = $this->Authsome->get('id');       

$this->paginate = array(

'conditions' => array(
'Qnote.id LIKE' => $id), 
   );
$data = $this->paginate('Qnote');
$this->set('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: BTW, no need for `'Qnote.id LIKE' => $id`. An SQL `LIKE` comparison will be much slower than a straight up `=` comparison, and a number can only be a number anyway. Get rid of the `LIKE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$qnote['Step']` is also a multidimensional array, so you'll need to loop through it too:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $qnote) : ?>
    <p>Id: <?php echo $qnote['Qnote']['id']; ?></p>
    <p>Body: <?php echo $qnote['Qnote']['body']; ?></p>
    <p>
        Steps:
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($qnote['Step'] as $step) : ?>
                <li><?php echo $step['body']; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make note:

```
<?php echo $qnote['Step']['body']; ?> // Doesnt Work ????
```

where `$qnote['Step']` is:

```
[Step] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [user_id] => 39
        [qnote_id] => 67
        [type] => a
        [body] => This is a text
     )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [user_id] => 39
        [qnote_id] => 67
        [type] => a
        [body] => This is userid 39
    )
)
```

There is no `$qnote['Step']['body']`. There's `$qnote['Step'][1]['body']`, though.

If you want to access ALL `['body']`s in `$qnote['Step']`, use `foreach`:

```
foreach($qnote['Step'] as $step)
{
    echo $step['body'];
}
```

edit: On second thought, also notice that 'Step' is NOT a member of 'Qnote' (and probably not $qnote.) You may want to address that first.

Comment: Re "second thought": That's a standard Cake result array. `Qnote` is the primary model and `Step` is a related hasMany or HABTM model. It's fine the way it is. :)

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, I've never used Cake before (obviously.)